# Connect two consecutive Doctrine mapped superclasses

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

As you can understand from the title, my question comes due to a legacy app on which I've this mapping:

```
/** @MappedSuperclass */
abstract class BaseUser
{
    // ... common fields (no associations)
}

/** @Entity */
class Admin extends BaseUser
{
    // ... with specific fields/associations for admin users
}

/** @Entity */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    // ... with specific fields/associations for front-end users
}
```

But now I will need to have 2 different user types with a different `dashboard` sections and I thought to make also the `User` class `abstract` to be extendable by the new 2 types:

```
/** @MappedSuperclass */
abstract class User extends BaseUser
{
    // ...
}

/** @Entity */
class StandardUser extends User
{
    // ... with specific fields/associations for standard users
}

/** @Entity */
class AgentUser extends User
{
    // ... with specific fields/associations for agent users
}
```

I already make some research and obviously I've also read the [Doctrine documentation about Mapped Superclasses](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses) but it's not clearly specified anywhere if it's possible to have two or more consecutive `MappedSuperclass`.

So my question is: Is this possible? And if not, there is an alternative?

PS: I use Symfony 3.2 and Doctrine 2.5

Comment: "Is this possible?" - have you tried doing this? Checking first would save you some time writing the question

Comment: @malarzm My idea was asking here if anyone already knows this (_I haven't found a similar question here on SO and could be useful for someone_) and after lunch try it myself and eventually answer my own question :-). PS: I would hope there is nothing wrong with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my own test on Doctrine 2.5 and Symfony >=3.2 I can confirm that (YES) it's possible to use two or more consecutive/chained Mapped Superclasses without any problem.

*NOTE: Also if check it yourself it's not a big waste of time, I think this information should be added in the Doctrine docs to clarify any possible dubt and because do it does not have any cost :-) (but I was the only to have this doubt?).*

Comment: *Mapped superclasses, just as regular, non-mapped classes, can appear in the middle of an otherwise mapped inheritance hierarchy (through Single Table Inheritance or Class Table Inheritance).* - it's already in the docs.

Comment: @ccKep Surely it's due to my low English knowledge but can you tell me which words exactly of this sentence (_can appear in the middle of an otherwise mapped inheritance hierarchy_) explain clearly that I can use two or more mapped superclasses **consecutively**. Just to improve my English :-)

Comment: "Mapped superclasses can appear in the middle of an otherwise mapped inheritance hierachy" - in the middle suggest's that there's something before and/or after.